# Skip weekends in php date

Tags: php

I have this code :

```
 for ($i = 2; $i > -3; $i--)
    { 
        $class="";

        if(date('D d-m')==date('D d-m', strtotime($i . ' days ago')))
        { 
          $class=' class="distinct"'; 
        }

        echo '<li'.$class.'>'.date('D d-m', strtotime($i . ' days ago')) . '</li>'.'<br />';

    }
```

And it outputs this:

```
Wed 17-05

Thu 18-05

Fri 19-05

Sat 20-05

Sun 21-05
```

I was wondering how i can skip the weekends, so it only shows the 5 days monday-friday. Any ideas how to exclude this?

Comment: So you want it to output the current week days? What if it is weekend?

Comment: if its weekend dont output it. so it will always only show monday to friday. and the current day must be like it is now, in the middle of the list. @Jerodev

Comment: So you want to output two days after now day and two days before.
If, for example now is friday, output must be:

-Wed
-Thu
-Mon
-Tue
Am I right?

Comment: if today is friday output should be : Monday - Tue -Friday-  Wed - Thu The current day in the middle @AndriySushchyk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by creating a timestamp for monday and adding enough seconds to advance a day five times.

Like so:

```
$monday = strtotime('last monday');
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    echo date('D d-m', $monday) . '<br />'; 
    $monday = $monday + (60 * 60 * 24); // Add a day
}
```

Comment: Works but i would like the current day in the middle

Comment: It's not possible to list the five non-weekend days in a week and put the current day always in the middle. That's only possible on a Wednesday...

Answer (score 1):

I thing [getDate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) is just what you need. Where you can use `'wday'` to check which day of the week it is (from 0 - Sunday, to 6 - Saturday). Example:

```
for ($i = 2; $i > -3; $i--)
{ 
    $date = getDate(strtotime($i . ' days ago'));
    if($date['wday'] == 6 || $date['wday'] == 0) {
        echo "Weekend!\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "Regular day...\n";
    }
}
```

And it outputs:

```
Regular day...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Regular day...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Regular day...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Weekend!                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Weekend!
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
for($i = -2; $i <= 2; $i++)
{
    echo date ( 'D d-m' , strtotime ( "$i weekdays" ) ) . '<br>';
}
```

Will output:

```
Wed 17-05
Thu 18-05
Fri 19-05
Mon 22-05
Tue 23-05
```

===================================

Old answer:

```
$thisMonday = date("d-M-Y", strtotime('monday this week'));

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++)
{ 
    $class="";

    $date = date('d-M-Y', strtotime("+$i days", strtotime($thisMonday)));

    if(date('D d-m') == date('D d-m', strtotime($i . ' days ago')))
    { 
      $class=' class="distinct"'; 
    }

    echo '<li'.$class.'>'. date('D d-m', strtotime($date)) . '</li>'.'<br />';

}
```

Comment: Works but i would like the current day in the middle